# How to get Version history of all fields updated for a list item?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, web-services, rest, versioning

I am developing a ticketing system on SharePoint 2013 onprem. I am storing Ticket data in a list with versioning enabled. On my user end (which is not a SharePoint solution, I can access only CSOM and SharePoint as a datasource), I need to display update history of the ticket whenever user edits it. It is similar to comments but only few fields are editable. I found [Lists.GetVersionCollection Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getversioncollection%28v=office.12%29.aspx) but it wont help as it requires looping through fields. Is there anything that can accomplish this in CSOM (a data service/webservice/web api/ any other api). I confirm it never existed in SP 2010. I want a view like this on my application:

[image: SharePoint Version history for a list item]

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen anything that will let you get that version information using the client api's.  Since it is an on-prem server you could write some server side code to use the [SPListItem.Versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.versions.aspx) functions to read the version info and return it to the client.  I haven't checked but that function may be accessible from a sandbox solutions as well, if you can't do a full trust farm solution.

Depending on what your consuming application is you could hit that page that you have in your screen shot (https:////_layouts/15/Versions.aspx?list={}&ID=1&isDlg=1) and parse the html to extract the data.  Not easy but possible using some other tools to read and parse the html.  Or you could even just show the page directly if the formatting and authentication is fine.